# Simple putchar program errors out, using eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, putchar

I'm new at this. In the below program, even though it works, I get an error which says - cannot open output file putchar.exe: permission denied. I tried debugging and this is what i got - 
$1 = 0xff
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
[New Thread 7868.0x1f3c]

I have no idea what the debugging info means... any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    printf("Press Enter: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    getchar();
    ch = 'H';
    putchar(ch);
    ch = 'i';
    putchar(ch);
    putchar('!');
    putchar('\n');
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You most likely have tried to debug something that went wrong, and have forgotten to close the debugging sessions - that locks the exe as it's currently in use.

Answer (score 0):

Your programm runs with no problems on my computer.

After inserting a character to the standard input, you'll get "Hi!" as output, and no matter which char you insert. If you want to save this char you may put it on a char variable.

I don't understand you error since there's no file to open here. Note that putchar prints a char into the standard output and not to a specific file, for this purpose you can use fputc().

Comment: I think will be (I just run it on my PC, also with eclipse). After getting a char from STDIN it will print H, i, !, \n and finish. I still don't understand why he used getchar() if he didn't save it or do somthing with that char.

Comment: He uses that to wait for Enter key-press. If the output you had was simply `Hi!` then it means `printf` did nothing.

Comment: Of course that the string in the printf will be printed. I'm sorry if what I said confused you. What I wanted to say is that atfer inserting a char (and no matter which char), only "Hi!" will be printed to STDIN. I'll edit my answer to clarify this point.

Comment: I have never used Eclipse working on C, but I am almost sure that it'll wait specifically till the Enter key is pressed, regardless of how many characters you have typed down, even no character at all.

Comment: Yes, getchar() waits for enter after some input. But this programm ignores the input.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I deleted the program from disk and wrote it all over again, worked fine. My confusion was also with fflush(stdout). I've found out that fflush(stdout) needs to be used in eclipse whenever you want a printf statement like the one in the above program to accept some kind of user input. fflush wasn't needed when I used to program in the Ubuntu terminal. Maybe something's stopping printf to buffer in windows or eclipse.. I haven't used any other IDE on windows.